# Haglund exostosis after one day of bad shoes?

Tags: walking, shoes

Yesterday I walked one day one shoes a bit tight near the heel. In fact I felt this from the start of the day. My little brother developed Haglund exostosis once. Is it possible to develop a Haglund's deformity after only one day of bad shoes?

Answer (score 1):

Haglund's deformity is [mainly genetic](http://www.anklecenter.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=183:haglunds-deformity&catid=120:achilles-heel-pain&Itemid=202) and depends on your type of foot. As your brother has already had this, I suspect you might have the same type of foot and therefore have a higher risk of getting the deformity that others. Also, it's

> When most people first *notice* Haglund’s deformity, it is because the
>   skin, bursa and other soft tissues at the back of the heel gets 
>   irritated as the knot of bone rubs against the heel counter in shoes

You might have had a latent Haglund's deformity, but haven't noticed it until you used bad shoes.

I would **strongly advice you to visit a professional**, and not rely on "internet experts" for this. The price you have to pay for following a bad advice here is too high to risk it.

However, once the pain and inflammation have gone a way, there are preventive measures you can take:
Prevention of Haglund's Deformity
Once your pain and inflammation is gone, you can try to prevent Haglund’s deformity by [[1]](http://www.anklecenter.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=183:haglunds-deformity&catid=120:achilles-heel-pain&Itemid=202):

- Wearing the best shoes for your foot type. You should high-heels and pumps if possible.
- Wear orthotics (custom arch supports) or over-the-counter orthotic devices
- Perform frequent Achilles tendon stretching exercises to prevent it from becoming tight again
- Avoiding running uphill when training. Try to run on softer surfaces and avoid concrete.